# AWS Billing Alerts: Send email and trigger Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-billing

What I'm trying to implement is that on the AWS billing alarm I want to send an email and invoke a lambda function written in python from where I want to update something in the database. So how can I get these both, I know that against alarm you can send an email to the user but how to do both when an alarm is triggered?

```
{
    "Type": "AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm",
    "Properties": {
        "AlarmName": "AWS Polly Alarm One",
        "AlarmDescription": "AWS Polly Alarm One",
        "ActionsEnabled": true,
        "OKActions": [],
        "AlarmActions": [
            "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXXX:Turn_Off_AWS_Polly_Send_Email_One"
        ],
        "InsufficientDataActions": [],
        "MetricName": "EstimatedCharges",
        "Namespace": "AWS/Billing",
        "Statistic": "Maximum",
        "Dimensions": [
            {
                "Name": "ServiceName",
                "Value": "AmazonPolly"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Currency",
                "Value": "USD"
            }
        ],
        "Period": 60,
        "EvaluationPeriods": 1,
        "DatapointsToAlarm": 1,
        "Threshold": 0,
        "ComparisonOperator": "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold",
        "TreatMissingData": "missing"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When configuring an Amazon CloudWatch alarm, you can specify an Amazon Simple Notification Service (SNS) topic. Messages relating to the alarm will be sent to this topic.

Amazon SNS is a 'publish-subscribe' model, meaning that recipients need to **subscribe** to the topic to receive a notification. [Subscription types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_Subscribe.html) include:

- Email
- AWS Lambda functions

*All* subscribers to a topic will receive messages sent to the topic.

When a subscribed AWS Lambda function receives a message from an SNS topic, it is provided with details of the alarm that triggered the message. You can use this information to store relevant data in the database.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I have added email and lambda in the subscriptions. One question I would to ask Does publishing message manually from the SNS topic triggers the Lambda Function ?

Comment: Yes. All subscribers would receive the message.